# Many regexp on a dynamic list

Tags: mysql, regex, dynamic, load, sql-like

I'm looking for a way to match a string against a dynamic list of strings (about ~200k).
Ex: rrabcdrr should match with %abcd%.
In order to do that, I'm currently using a mysql database and use LIKE.

The thing is, there is constantly a lot of requests at the same time of this kind on the mysql server and I would like to find another way to do that. Is that possible to do that in any other technology, and as quickly as mysql? The load of the server is my main problem (I use memory table)

Any idea would be greatly appreciated

Comment: First thought that comes to mind is some sort of caching. Are there common searches that would take advantage of caching?

Comment: The match can be often the same, but the input is every time different. Ex: rrabcdrr match with %abcd%, ttabcd match with %abcd%, etc.. There is a lot of not common search as well though

Comment: If "something, abcd, something" is a common request, and "abcd" is the string you're looking for, then you can check your inputs for a string in string match on "abcd" and correspond that to a stored DB index.